# Have an image replacement galler want large image to be replaced by video when clicked

Tags: jquery, image, video, gallery, replace

I have a image replacement gallery and when I click a thumbnail a larger image appears in the main div. I wish to click this image and have it play a video, I would like a different video to play for each of the larger images clicked. All videos are on youtube.
Here is the code and script I have so far:

```
    <div class="videogallery">
    <img id="largeImg" src="/images/locationbased_largeclicktoplay.jpg" alt="Location-Based Video" />
</div>
              <div><hr /></div>
 <div class="thumbnails">
             <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; color:#466ea9;font-family:'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; text-align:left; padding-bottom:10px;">Videos</p>
             <p style=" text-align:center;">    
             <a href="/images/logo_largeclick.jpg" title="Social Media 101 Video">
             <img src="/images/logo_small.jpg" border="0" height="61" width="100" style="padding-right:10px;" /></a> 
             <a href="/images/facebook_large.jpg" title="Facebook Video">
             <img src="/images/facebook_small.jpg" border="0" height="61" width="100" style="padding-right:10px;"/></a> 
             <a href="/images/twitter_largeclicktoplay.jpg" title="Twitter Video">
             <img src="/images/twitter_small.jpg"border="0" height="61" width="100" style="padding-right:10px;"/></a>
             <a href="/images/youtube_largeclicktoplay.jpg" title="Youtube Video">
             <img src="U/images/youtube_s.jpg" border="0" height="61" width="100" style="padding-right:10px;"/></a>
  </div>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){


$(".thumbnails a").click(function(){

    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");

    $("#largeImg").attr({ src: largePath, alt: largeAlt });

    $("h2 em").html(" (" + largeAlt + ")"); return false;
});
```

});

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank You.
-Ann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it I added a script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var embedCode = '<object data="http://blip.tv/play/gYMo_vAmAA" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="500" width="600">
<param name="src" value="http://blip.tv/play/gYMo_vAmAA">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"></object>'
</script>
```

and  `onclick`:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('videocontainer').innerHTML = embedCode;"
```

to the `image` tag

I will probably add a different variable to the script for each thumbmail.